# Regression tree does not perform well

Tags: python, regression, decision-tree

My target is continuous value like house price. I am training a regression tree on it. I use Gradientboostregressor in scklearn, Python.

My target value(house price) has a L shape distribution: house price on high end is like 10 times higher than price on low end. My regression tree model under-predict high values, and over-predict low values.

Anything I can do to improve model prediction? I tried to model log(price), then exp(prediction),but not work well.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think that house prices are a continuous value. Did you normalize the data?

Comment: How is your training and testing data separated? does your training data contain houses with prices that are well distributed throughout the range of home prices? It's hard to say exactly what is failing without more information on the specific task. Likely, there are also preprocessing tricks you could use to attain better results. One example is you could try to segment low and high priced houses using a decision (classification) tree first, and then train a regression tree for each. Again, more info is needed to provide meaningful feedback.

Comment: House prices are continuous in that they come from the set of all real numbers (within some reasonable bounds).

Comment: @DerekG,  thanks, will try segment low/high income. i think it should help

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you can try:

1) Are there features that capture high price? Things like lat/long, square footage etc.

2) How large is your test set? Is it representative of the validation set?

Also, there is a number of posts analyzing this exact problem on US data. For example, this post from kaggle for some useful features that can work:
https://www.kaggle.com/erick5/predicting-house-prices-with-machine-learning

Comment: thanks, I am studying the Kaggle example,  they work with skewed the data (not as skew as mine), but why --we fix all of the skewed data to be more normal so that our models will be more accurate when making predictions.       Traditional stat model needs to make target normal, but why ML also need to fix it?

Comment: You are right. It depends on the type of model you train. It's important for logistic regression, but for trees that you use here it's not as important - as long as order of points in the axis the same, trees find similar splits without normalization.

Answer (score 0):

A single decision tree often does not work very well.  Of course you could try to optimize the tree. But I think it is better to change to random forest or gradient boosting if you want to work with trees.